# Given a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^3$, can its effects on a compact subset be realized by a homeomorphism that's non-identity only on a compact set?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $f_1 \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a homeomorphism, and let $K_1 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be compact. Does there always exist a homeomorphism $f_2 \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and a compact $K_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

1. $K_1 \subseteq K_2$
2. $f_1(K_1) = f_2(K_1)$
3. $f_2$ is identity on $\mathbb{R}^3 - K_2^\circ$?

(Hypothesis 1 is probably unnecessary in light of (2) and (3), I just thought it might be clearer to include)

Comment: Not necessarily if $f_1$ is orientation-reversing, but if you assume it preserves orientation, I would guess yes.

Comment: This is true in all dimensions, provided that $f$ is orientation-preserving, since $f$ will ne isotopic to identity. See my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386205/stability-question-for-isotopies-between-compact-sets/386762#386762).

Comment: Wow, excellent --- thank you very much! This is very helpful.